# Why not do without the body tag and use Meteor.startup template instead?

Tags: meteor

Using meteor release blaze-rc1, does this make sense:

client side

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
UI.insert(UI.render(Template.main), document.body); 
});

<template name="main">
this is the starting template
</template>
```

Are there side effects? Seems to work fine, and I don't have to worry about chasing down the body tag mixed in my templates. Sorry if this is a noob question, it's my first project with meteor.

Having body tags sprinkled in your code (and head tags for that matter) and expecting it to land in the correct order, feels a little bizarre. Must be my file / page world view.. perhaps I'm just old.

Comment: I personally don't see anything wrong with `body` tag as it is actually the `main` template which can be splitted in parts. I.e. you can have several `body` sections and they get concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a body tag Meteor automatically puts one in and then renders your template within that body tag.

I don't see any reason why you would really need to include the `<body>` tag at all. It certainly doesn't seem to do any harm.